# How to change video aspect ratio of vlc media player in python

Tags: python, vlc, aspect-ratio

I want to know how to change video aspect ratio of vlc media player in python to 16:10. Note that  I am using vlc module. my code is as below:

```
import vlc
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self._instance = vlc.Instance(['--video-on-top'])
        self._player = self._instance.media_player_new()
        self._player.set_fullscreen(True)

    def play(self, path):
        media = self._instance.media_new(path)
        self._player.set_media(media)
        self._player.play()

    def stop(self):
        self._player.stop()
p=Player()
p.play('C:\\Users\\Keshavarz\\Desktop\\a.mp4')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `video_set_aspect_ratio("n:n")` option where `"n:n"` is any of the usual suspects "16:9", "4:3" etc but can be anything you want such as "2:5" for example.

You will also need to keep the script alive, I've included a simple loop in your `play` function, to do that.

```
import vlc
import time
class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self._instance = vlc.Instance(['--video-on-top'])
        self._player = self._instance.media_player_new()
        #self._player.set_fullscreen(True)
        self._player.video_set_aspect_ratio("16:9")

    def play(self, path):
        media = self._instance.media_new(path)
        self._player.set_media(media)
        self._player.play()
        playing = set([1,2,3,4])
        time.sleep(0.1)
        while True:
            state = self._player.get_state()
            if state not in playing:
                break
            time.sleep(1)

    def stop(self):
        self._player.stop()
p=Player()
p.play('C:\\Users\\Keshavarz\\Desktop\\a.mp4')
```